# Lower Envelope of a Function is Measurable

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb{\overline R}$ be arbitrary, then define the lower envelope

$$f_*(x):=\lim_{\delta\to 0,\delta> 0}\inf\{f(z)\;|\;z\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)\}$$

We want to show $f_*$ is $\mathfrak M_L$-measurable.

I was wondering if my proof was correct or where the argument breaks down.

Proof: Look at 
$$A=\{ f_*(x)>a \}$$
for some arbitrary $a\in \mathbb R$.

Let $x_0\in A\implies\exists \delta >0$ s.t. $\inf\{f(z)\;|\;z\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\}>a\implies$

$$\forall x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$$

$$\inf\{f(z)\;|\;z\in \mathbb B(x,|x-x_0|)\cap(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta) \}\geq$$

$$\inf\{f(z)\;|\;z\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\}>a$$

$$(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\subset A$$
Thus $A$ is open and measurable for any $a\in\mathbb R$.$\blacksquare$

Comment: you got the right idea. But there are some technical errors. You should show that $\inf f > a$ on $\mathbb B(x, |x-x_0|)$. The intersection is not sufficient. It is easier if you assume $x\in \mathbb B(x_0, \delta/2)$ and consider $\inf f$ on $\mathbb B(x, \delta/2)$

Comment: I didn't explicitly say it but the intersection of two open sets is open so we should be able to find some $\varepsilon$ s.t. $\mathbb B (x,\varepsilon)\subset \mathbb B (x_0,\delta)$

Comment: But that was crucial. To be exact, you only need that an open ball is indeed open. The other points you mentioned are not that interesting...

Comment: I thought that was obvious..